# How to declare Foreign Key in a physical file through DDS in AS/400?

Tags: key, ibm-midrange, data-distribution-service

We can make foreign keys very easily using SQL. But is there any way to declare foreign key using DDS?

Comment: I think no special keyword in DDS. Without SQL normally use command ADDPFCST, with Constraint type *REFCST. You can read more by searching "Referential Integrity"

Comment: It can't be done with DDS alone. It must be combined with CL (or SQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As IamLam pointed out, DDS doesn't directly support constraints in the source; you have to use ADDPFCST after the fact.

I'm assuming you don't have a change management system.  In that case, you could do one of two things

Switch to SQL DDL - there's basically no difference between an SQL created table and DDS created file.  IBM actually provides a utility to generate SQL DDL for an object regardless of rather or not it was created with DDS or DDL in the first place.

Use a pre-compiler for your DDS.  One open source one I've heard about is Alan Campin's `COMPILE`
http://think400.dk/downloads.htm

Actually you could use either of the above with a CMS also, but if you had a CMS you probably wouldn't be asking the question as it should take care of creating the constraint when the file is changed.